# Next.js with Suspense: Fallback UI Not Displaying on Refresh

Tags: next.js

Using Next.js version 13 with the app directory, I'm encountering an issue with Suspense's fallback UI.

Below is the client-side component structure I've set up for fetching data:

```
// page.tsx

'use client';

import UsequeryComp from 'app/components/UsequeryComp';
import { Suspense } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  return (
      <Suspense fallback={<div>useQuery loading...</div>}>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-500">
          <UsequeryComp />
        </div>
      </Suspense>
  );
}


// UsequeryComp.tsx
'use client';

import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { axiosPostQuery } from 'app/api/route';
import React from 'react';

import { Post } from '@/type';

const UsequeryComp = () => {
  const { data: posts } = useQuery(['posts'], axiosPostQuery);

  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post: Post) => (
        <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default UsequeryComp;


// api
export const axiosPostQuery = async () => {
  await wait(3000);

  const response = await axios.get(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  );
  return response.data;
};
```

Upon accessing the root page in the browser, a loading indication appears. However, after refreshing the page multiple times, this loading indication intermittently fails to show, making it seem like the data is being cached.

Is there a way to prevent this caching behavior and ensure that the loading indicator displays every time I refresh the page? Currently, after a few refreshes, the loading indication stops appearing and the data is immediately returned instead.

I did the following

Changed both tanstack-query cacheTime and staleTime to 0.

I used axios because the fetch function was likely cached.
I didn't give it any cache settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try use 'queryClient.invalidateQueries' or 'queryClient.refetchQueries'.

By using this methods from tanstack-query, you can imperatively refetch data.

```
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const queryClient = useQueryClient();

// To refetch a query when a certain condition occurs
const refetchData = () => {
  queryClient.refetchQueries(['myData']);
};

// To invalidate a query, marking it as stale
const invalidateData = () => {
  queryClient.invalidateQueries(['myData']);
};
```

Also, make sure your your cache-contrl header of axios be 'no-cache' or 'no-store' to prevent default browser cache.